# execCommand insert image always add another image after the inserted image

Tags: javascript, jquery, execcommand

I am using insertImage to input an image into my rich text editor, but whenever I insert an image, there is another img tag produced after the image I put as follows:

```
        <img src="null"/>
```

This is my code.

```
        $(insertImageBtn).click(function() {
        var url = "https://";
        var input= prompt("Please enter a url", url);
        if (input !== null) {
            iframeDocument.execCommand('insertImage', false, input);
        }
    });
```

How to get rid of it?

Comment: Make sure that you "insertImageBtn" is not a class and existing maybe on two places?

Comment: Did you solved it?